# why I can't create an index in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a collection in mongodb where i can't create an index

this is a field, i want make index.

```
"indexContents" : ["‘", "‘e", "‘ea", "‘eat", "e", "ea", "eat", "a", "at", "t", "&", "d", "dr", "dri", "drin", "drink", "drink’", "r", "ri", "rin", "rink", "rink’", "i", "in", "ink", "ink’", "n", "nk", "nk’", "k", "k’", "’"]
```

what's wrong in my field?

I can index, title, street, everything just fine.

However when I created index that contain indexContents I got this error:

```
Wed Aug 29 05:50:33 Socket recv() errno:104 Connection reset by peer 127.0.0.1:27017
Wed Aug 29 05:50:33 SocketException: remote: 127.0.0.1:27017 error: 9001 socket exception [1] server [127.0.0.1:27017]
Wed Aug 29 05:50:34 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Wed Aug 29 05:50:34 query failed : hello.$cmd { getlasterror: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1
Wed Aug 29 05:50:34 Error: error doing query: failed shell/collection.js:151
Wed Aug 29 05:50:34 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1
Wed Aug 29 05:50:34 reconnect 127.0.0.1 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1
```

I think one of the data is "messed up" but which one out of 1.6 million data?

update:
I already repairDatabase but i got the same resutl, can't create indexContent

Notice other ensure index is fine.

For example, I can index indexContents alone fine

I can index 
{LongitudeLatitude:"2d",Prominent:1}

{indexContents:1} fine

Things fail if when I tried to index

{LongitudeLatitude:"2d",indexContents:1,Prominent:1}

Comment: That looks like an internal error (or maybe a network error, such as a timeout). Do you have any server-side log?

Comment: What does `getLastError` say?

Comment: That's what getLastError actually says and not the logs?

Comment: yes not the logs mongodb, this error from mongodb shell

Comment: Ok I googled the error code, I got a few possibilties: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/VOxqTNTNyyc http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/127jjm3fy9/mongo-reports-a-error-9001-socket-exception-every-10-seconds-while-using-the-c-driver

Comment: I don't think my problem is there. I mean this is a really basic setup for mongodb. There is no sharding or anything. Other indexes are fine. In fact, I can index indexContents:1 just fine. If when I created compound indexes like {LongitudeLatitude:"2d",indexContents:1,Prominent:1} I am in trouble.

Comment: Can you include an example document with the LongitudeLatitude field?  I suspect that may be the problem .. perhaps you have some values which are not the expected array.  Also, as suggested you should check the error in the mongod server log as it may be more specific than the client exception which essentially just means "server has gone away".